# Android: Navigate to custom home screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation, homescreen

I would like to achieve the back navigation (by pressing home button in the Action Bar) as it shows the attached picture.
As you can see the login screen is visited once and it takes the user to Activity B. When pressing an item it takes the user to a new instance of Activity B and so on. Think this such as a files navigation app with a login included.

So, my question is, which is the most elegant way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

[image: Application structure]

Comment: "Don't change the users expectations" when the user hits the `Home` button they expect to leave your app and go to their home screen (this is also what Android documentation stress out) Most elegant solution, add a button on the action bar which takes the user back to the initial state, implementation is really dependent on your code.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do what you want is to make your app a launcher app. meaning it would replace the launcher that the user currently uses for their home screen.

If that is not what you want to achieve then you are out of luck because you cannot override the home button for security purposes.

EDIT:

if you want to use the up navigation then send an intent. see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) on how to use the up navigation

Comment: Edited my question, I changed to "home button in Action Bar" instead

Comment: then all you have to do is start a new intent to the activity you want. see the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: From the docs "With this flag (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), if the activity you're starting already exists in the current task, then all activities on top of it are destroyed and it is brought to the front. Adding this flag is often important because going "home" is an action that's equivalent to "going back" and you should usually not create a new instance of the home activity". So the question is: how can I keep a reference for the first B activity?

Comment: if the activity is already in the backstack (which is should in your case) all it does is brings that activity to the front and clears anything below that activity

Comment: Please read my question again. How can I identify which Activity is my FIRST B activity?

Comment: your design really does not make sense, there should not be different `B` activities. all activities should be different ie. A,B,C,D.. passing any information needed in the intent; that way if you navigate back it does not need to know what it is. If you are passing information down than all you have to do is supply what information you got navigating through then pass it back in the intent to the beginning activity

Comment: That's impossible for me. Think this as a file explorer app which the FilesActivity contains the files and folders pertaining to the current path. After you tap other folder the same activity should be called with a different path and so on.

Comment: like i said you will have to pass the data along with each activity and pass whatever info you need back to that activity when the up button is pressed. without more detail there is no much more I can tell you. or just skip using the up button all together